# XML parsing - the ^H character/symbol?

Tags: python, xml, string, parsing

I'm having a really bad time trying to clean up some XML so I can parse it in Python with etree. Basically before my Python script reads it, I'm trying to escape all the special characters in each string entry that are giving me

```
'xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed'
```

So while I'm generating the XML string entries, I'm using `sed` to replace special characters with either their escaped versions or just a `space` when I really don't care.

But now in my generated XML I'm seeing a `^H` character, which vim has highlighted as blue.

I tried escaping the `^` but that didn't work, the character remains so I'm thinking it must be some kind of composite special character.

Sigh why does this suck so much. Anyways thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you get a backspace character *into* the XML in the first place?

Comment: It's probably a backspace (ASCII 8 or Control-H). Without knowing exactly what kind of cleaning up you're doing or seeing some of the file, it'll be hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

`^H` is a common way to represent a backspace character embedded in text (ASCII character 8); if you are already using `sed`/`bash` for filtering, you can do:

```
cat infile | sed s/$'\b'// > outfile
```

Still, I don't think it's a good thing you had a ^H in your input file in first place... how are you generating it?

Comment: Honestly.. I'm just reading log files from some project directories. Could you help explain your solution a bit? I'm new to sed/bash stuff.

Comment: @YoungMoney: I simplified/corrected the code, now it should be straightforward (`$'\b'` is just the bash way to input your `^H`).

Comment: One more question just to make sure - so I can use this to modify one file, i.e. `infile` is the same as `outfile`? EDIT - because I tried that and now I have an empty file as a result...

Comment: @YoungMoney: no; `sed` reads from a file (or stdin) and outputs to stdout; the stream redirection operator (`>`) truncates the file before starting the pipeline, so you end up with an empty file. You have to output to a temporary file and overwrite the original after `sed` has finished.